# File Upload Not Working In Boostrap Tab

Tags: file, tabs, upload, bootstrap-4, input-type-file

I am developing a web page where the user needs to upload a file. I am using a general technique that sits on top of the  \input type="file"\ element that enables me to style it better.

This works fine until I put it in a Bootstrap 4 tab where it appears that the element stops receiving it's Click event.

To demonstrate this I have an HTML page using Jquery and Bootstrap. I have the similar elements sitting inside and outside of the tab.  When I click the 'Browse' button on the elements outside the tab it works as expect. However when I click on the 'Browse button inside the tab nothing happens.  You need to select "tab 2" then "tab 1" to get the the first tab's content to appear.

There must something in the Bootstrap tab that is blocking this.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as I need to use tabs ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>File Upload</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
</style> 

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true" href="#tab1Content">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false" href="#tab2Content">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="tab1Content" data-toggle="tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1">
                <div class="row pb-5">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <p>Inside of tab</p>
                            <input type="file" id="fileUploader" name="fileUploader" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                            <input class="form-control input-xlarge" type="text" id="fileName" value="Choose file">

                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button id="browseButton" name="browseButton" class="btn btn-success input-group-text">Browse</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2Content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <p>Outside of tab</p>
                <input type="file" id="fileUploader2" name="fileUploader2" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                <input class="form-control input-xlarge" type="text" id="fileName2" value="Choose file">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="browseButton2" name="browseButton2" class="btn btn-success input-group-text">Browse</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        

        $('#browseButton').on('click', function () {
            $('#fileUploader').click();
        });

        $('#fileUploader').change(function () {
            $('#fileName').val($(this).val());
        });

        $('#browseButton2').on('click', function () {
            $('#fileUploader2').click();
        });

        $('#fileUploader2').change(function () {
            $('#fileName2').val($(this).val());
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code snippet. Might be your HTML tags were not closed properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>File Upload</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
</style> 

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                <p>Inside of tab</p>
                <input type="file" id="fileUploader" name="fileUploader" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                <input class="form-control input-xlarge" type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName" value="Choose file">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="browseButton" name="browseButton" class="btn btn-success input-group-text">Browse</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            Nulla est ullamco ut irure incididunt nulla Lorem Lorem minim irure officia enim reprehenderit. Magna duis labore cillum sint adipisicing exercitation ipsum. Nostrud ut anim non exercitation velit laboris fugiat cupidatat. Commodo esse dolore fugiat sint velit ullamco magna consequat voluptate minim amet aliquip ipsum aute laboris nisi. Labore labore veniam irure irure ipsum pariatur mollit magna in cupidatat dolore magna irure esse tempor ad mollit. Dolore commodo nulla minim amet ipsum officia consectetur amet ullamco voluptate nisi commodo ea sit eu.
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            Sint sit mollit irure quis est nostrud cillum consequat Lorem esse do quis dolor esse fugiat sunt do. Eu ex commodo veniam Lorem aliquip laborum occaecat qui Lorem esse mollit dolore anim cupidatat. Deserunt officia id Lorem nostrud aute id commodo elit eiusmod enim irure amet eiusmod qui reprehenderit nostrud tempor. Fugiat ipsum excepteur in aliqua non et quis aliquip ad irure in labore cillum elit enim. Consequat aliquip incididunt ipsum et minim laborum laborum laborum et cillum labore. Deserunt adipisicing cillum id nulla minim nostrud labore eiusmod et amet. Laboris consequat consequat commodo non ut non aliquip reprehenderit nulla anim occaecat. Sunt sit ullamco reprehenderit irure ea ullamco Lorem aute nostrud magna.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <p>Outside of tab</p>
                <input type="file" id="fileUploader2" name="fileUploader2" style="visibility:hidden;" />
                <input class="form-control input-xlarge" type="text" id="fileName2" value="Choose file">

                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="browseButton2" name="browseButton2" class="btn btn-success input-group-text">Browse</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        

        $('#browseButton').on('click', function () {
            $('#fileUploader').click();
        });

        $('#fileUploader').change(function () {
            $('#fileName').val($(this).val());
        });

        $('#browseButton2').on('click', function () {
            $('#fileUploader2').click();
        });

        $('#fileUploader2').change(function () {
            $('#fileName2').val($(this).val());
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ady: Did you went through the answer.

Comment: I have now spotted what is wrong.  My tab content divs had a data-toggle="tab" attribute which should not have been there,  these exist on the anchors in the list items.  Probably a cut and paste error.  I guessed it would have been something like this.  Thank you for your reply, your working code proved that there was something wrong with my code,  it was just difficult to pin down and became a task of compare and contrast.